# Is it possible to associate a file type with a .cmd file so it sends that file as an argument when double clicked

Tags: cmd, file-type, file-association

i have a dostuff.cmd file that takes one argument and looks something like this:

```
filepath_to_command_to_run %1
```

If I type dostuff.cmd FILE into the command prompt it runs fine.

Is it even remotely possible to get it so that I can associate that file type with my dostuff.cmd so that if I double click a file the .cmd will get it as an argument?  Right now I've associated the file type with it, but when I double click it runs the stuff in the .cmd without getting the file as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the file -> Open With -> Choose Default Program -> Browse to and select your cmd file. ( Choose the checkbox saying always use this for this file type if you want)

Now double clicking the file will open it with the cmd file.

Alternatively, you can set it directly to `filepath_to_command_to_run`

Comment: I've done that, but when I double click the file it runs only the filepath_to_command_to_run and doesn't provide the file as an argument so all I get is the commands help and then the cmd window closes.

Comment: @Chris - I have confirmed that the file comes in as `%1` - it should work, unless the command expects something else as well and that is why it is showing the help

Comment: Interesting.  The command doesn't need anymore arguments.  I suppose I should mention I'm on windows 7.  I don't know if that makes a difference.  Also, it works if I drag and drop the file on the cmd file.

Answer (score 0):

Once I have achieved the correct way of FILE ASSOCIATION using these cmd commands. 
this is just an example:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad++.exe\shell\open\command" /v @ /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\\Program Files\\Noteepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\"" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt" /v "Application" /t REG_SZ /d "notepad++.exe" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt\OpenWithList" /v "g" /t REG_SZ /d "notepad++.exe" /f

assoc .txt=MyCustomType
ftype MyCustomType="C:\Program Files\Noteepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
```

(it's better to put them in .bat file)